# Replace url with ellipses

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm showing url path for every page showing where the user is exactly. Like if user came to home->mobile->design then I'm showing user path like "home/mobile/design". everything is working fine but for mobile I have to hide content between home and design like home/.../design. I'm not sure how to implement this. Can someone help.... Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't, or how to make, this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Why do you have to hide part of the path? If they can't see the entire path, what's the point of even having any of it because it's not helpful to them at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

New example with toggling content:

```
var url = 'home/mobile/design';

var start = url.indexOf('/');
var end = url.lastIndexOf('/');
var finalString = url.substring(0,start+1) + '...' + url.substring(end, url.length);

$('#myURL').text(finalString);

$('#myURL').click(function(){
 if(!$('#myURL').hasClass('toggle')){
    $('#myURL').text(url);
  $('#myURL').addClass('toggle');
  }else{
    $('#myURL').text(finalString);
  $('#myURL').removeClass('toggle');  
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2mq0dwbd/1/

This code will do what you want:

```
var url = 'home/mobile/design';

var start = url.indexOf('/');
var end = url.lastIndexOf('/');

alert(url.substring(0,start+1) + '...' + url.substring(end, url.length))
```

This code will account for another variants as well, if you have more "sections" inside it will only take the first one and the last one:

```
home/some/deep/section/goes/here
```

result:

```
home/.../here
```

You can play with it and modify it to meet your particular needs, of course.

Hope it helps!

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2mq0dwbd/

Comment: Thanks! It's working as expected. But How can I make this ellipse as clickable. I mean when I click on the ellipse(...) it should expand the whole url path

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to use slice/substring you can use a regex which results in a smaller amount of code:

```
var test = 'home/mobile/design';
test.replace(/\/.*\//, '/.../'); // home/.../design
```

It also works for different versions:

```
var test2 = 'home/mobile/design/test'; 
test2.replace(/\/.*\//, '/.../'); // home/.../test
```